# When navigating from WizardsPage1 to 2 through next, how to force the user to remain on the same page if Progress Bar cancel button is clicked?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, wizard

I have a wizard page like below-

[image]

When the Next button is clicked, the progess bar is shown as seen below-

[image]

If the Progess bar activity is cancelled, I want to keep the user on the same page from where the next button is clicked. How can I achieve this?

I am doing the below to show the progress bar of the WizardPage2

```
@Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            InterfacePage interfacePage = (InterfacePage) (getWizard().getPage("NewInterfacePage"));
            String interfaceId = interfacePage.getInterfaceID();
            
            try {
                getContainer().run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {

                    @Override
                    public void run(IProgressMonitor arg0) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
                        int amount = 10;
                        arg0.beginTask("Fetching details from External System...", 10);
                        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                            arg0.internalWorked(1);
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            if (arg0.isCanceled()) {
                                cancelled = true;
                                
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        super.setVisible(visible);
    }
```

---

## Sample Code which fails-

The main Wizard-

```
public class TemplateCreationWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard, IExecutableExtension {

    private InterfacePage interfacePage;
    private InterfaceDetailsPage interfaceDetailsPage;
    private ErrorPage error;
    private IConfigurationElement _configurationElement;

    private SelectedServerNode iServer;

    public TemplateCreationWizard() {
        setWindowTitle("Auto Development");
    }

    @Override
    public void addPages() {
        super.addPages();

        if (iServer.isConnected()) {
            interfacePage = new InterfacePage(iServer);
            interfaceDetailsPage = new InterfaceDetailsPage(iServer);

            addPage(interfacePage);
            addPage(interfaceDetailsPage);

            setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
        } else {
            error = new ErrorPage(iServer);
            addPage(error);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
        // will do something
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) {

        try {
            TreeSelection treeSelection = (TreeSelection) selection;

            TreePath[] treePaths = treeSelection.getPaths();
            if (null != treePaths && treePaths.length > 0) {
                TreePath treePath = treePaths[0];
                ISServerNode serverNode = (ISServerNode) treePath.getFirstSegment();
                ServerConnection iData = serverNode.getServerConnection();
                if (null != iData) {
                    iServer = createSelectedServerNode(iData);
                    // do domething
                }
            } else {
                // ... logic in case appropriate node is not selected
                System.out.println("<empty selection>");
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setInitializationData(IConfigurationElement config, String propertyName, Object data)
            throws CoreException {
        _configurationElement = config;

    }


    @Override
    public IWizardPage getNextPage(final IWizardPage page) {
        if (!(page instanceof InterfacePage))  //Next page from first page?
            return super.getNextPage(page);

         //Moving from first to second page, run the progress

        try {
            getContainer().run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {

                @Override
                public void run(IProgressMonitor arg0) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
                    int amount = 10;
                    arg0.beginTask("Fetching details from External System...", 10);
                    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                        arg0.internalWorked(1);
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
             //TODO deal with error
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             //Cancelled
            return null;  //Stay on same page
        }
        return super.getNextPage(page);
    }
}
```

**Wizard Pages-**

**Page 1 -**

```
public class InterfacePage extends WizardPage {
    private SelectedServerNode iServer = null;

    private class CompleteListener implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            boolean hasInterfaceID = !"".equals(getTextFrom(interfaceId));
            if (!hasInterfaceID) {
                setMessage("Please enter an Interface ID", IMessageProvider.ERROR);
            }
            if (hasInterfaceID) {
                setMessage(null);
            }
            setPageComplete(hasInterfaceID);
        }
    }

    private Text interfaceId;
    protected InterfacePage(SelectedServerNode iServer) {
        super("InterfacePage");

        this.iServer = iServer;
        setTitle("Some title");
        setMessage("Some message");
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite page = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        setControl(page);
        setPageComplete(false);

        // page.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 2;
        gridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = false;
        page.setLayout(gridLayout);

        page.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

        Label label = new Label(page, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Interface ID:");

        interfaceId = new Text(page, SWT.BORDER);
        GridData interfaceIdGridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        interfaceId.setLayoutData(interfaceIdGridData);

        CompleteListener listener = new CompleteListener();
        interfaceId.addKeyListener(listener);

    }
    

    @Override
    public boolean canFlipToNextPage()
    {
      // Default calls getNextPage() which runs the progress just checking page complete is enough here
      return isPageComplete();
    }
    
    
    private String getTextFrom(Text text) {
        return text == null || text.isDisposed() ? null : text.getText();
    }

    public String getInterfaceID() {
        return getTextFrom(interfaceId);
    }

}
```

**Page 2 -**

```
public class InterfaceDetailsPage extends WizardPage {
    
    private SelectedServerNode iServer;
    
    protected InterfaceDetailsPage(SelectedServerNode iServer) {
        super("InterfaceDetailsPage");
        
        this.iServer = iServer;
        setTitle("Interface ID details");
        setMessage("Provided Interface ID details is shown below");
    }
    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        
            Composite page = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            setControl(page);
            page.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public IWizard getWizard() {
        IWizard wizard = super.getWizard();
        return wizard;
    }
    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        
        if (visible) {
            InterfacePage interfacePage = (InterfacePage) (getWizard().getPage("InterfacePage"));
            String interfaceId = interfacePage.getInterfaceID();
            // do something...
        }
        super.setVisible(visible);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @greg-449: Any suggestions.

Comment: Note - you can't use `@xxx` to contact someone unless they have already commented on the question

Comment: @greg-449: Noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do a progress bar between pages is to override the `getNextPage` method of your `Wizard` class. `getNextPage` can return `null` to stop the change.

```
@Override
public IWizardPage getNextPage(final IWizardPage page)
{
  if (!(page instanceof YourFirstPage))  // Next page from first page?
    return super.getNextPage(page);

  // Moving from first to second page, run the progress

  try
   {
     getContainer().run .....
   }
  catch (InvocationTargetException ex)
   {
     // TODO deal with error
   }
  catch (InterruptedException ex)
   {
     // Cancelled
     return null;  // Stay on same page
   }

  return super.getNextPage(page);
}
```

You will also need to override `canFlipToNextPage` in your first WizardPage as the default calls `getNextPage`:

```
@Override
public boolean canFlipToNextPage()
{
  // Default calls getNextPage() which runs the progress just checking page complete is enough here
  return isPageComplete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will surely accept the same once I have tested it.

Comment: I wanted the progress bar to come only when the Next button on the first page is clicked. Now the moment the user puts something into the text field(on the first page), the progress bar is shown which is not what I wanted in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't even lets me finish the text which I want to put inside the text field. How can I avoid this behavior. If I go with yr solution showing the progress bar on the first page itself, how to make the progress bar show only when the user is done with the text entered in the input field.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you also have to override `canFlipToNextPage` in the first WizardPage to stop that behaviour - see updated answer

Comment: It still navigates to Wizard Page 2, after the progress bar red button.

Comment: The `isPageComplete` will return true as I have explicitly not set it to false, and hence it will go to next page everytime. Do I need to set it explicitly and which place is appropriate for the same?

Comment: isPageComplete just determines if the Next button is enabled, it is getNextPage that actually controls if the next page is shown when Next is pressed. This code works for me here. Are you getting the InterruptedException and returning null on the cancel.

Comment: No, on cancellation, there is no exception thrown and hence return null doesn't gets executed. I have attached the whole sample code. Please suggest.

Comment: Any reasons as to why I am not getting Interrupted exception?

Comment: Not sure. Possibly you need to throw an InterruptedException when the isCanceled is set in the progress monitor

Comment: Thanks very much. I have learnt a lot through your answers on stackoverflow. I am new to all this wizard API. I didn't want to pollute this thread with multiple questions. So I have raised another one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151587/how-to-update-controls-on-a-wizard-page.

Comment: If there any other way through which I can track whether the cancel operation on the progress bar was called?

Comment: It works fine if I explicitly threw InterruptedException, but in a long running activity how to track whether the task was cancelled. I know the IProgressMonitor#isCanceled() tracks that, but do I have to check this flag at some regular intervals and then threw the exception. Kindly advise.

Comment: Yes you have to keep checking isCancelled. Java does not have a way to cleanly terminate a thread.