# How to update controls on a wizard page?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, wizard

I have a wizard consisting of 2 wizard pages.

```
@Override
public void addPages() {
    super.addPages();
    addPage(firstPage);
    addPage(secondPage);    
}
```

I see that the `createControl` method of both the pages gets called immediately when the wizard is shown.

The first wizard page has a text field. I want to display the same text value on the second page entered by the user on the first page when he navigates from first page to the send page.

How can I achieve this?  How can I update the controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically up to you to arrange.

For example, you could pass a reference to firstPage to the secondPage when it is constructed. The `setVisible` method of the second page can then call some method on the first page to get the value you need.

Comment: The second page createControl method is executed even before User did something on the first page. If the second page contains an text field which should have a value equal to the what the user inputted on the first wizard page, what is the procedure to update the text field on the second page

Comment: I know on the second page, I can get the value of the text inpuutted by the user on the first page through `FirstPage firstPage = (FirstPage) (getWizard().getPage("FirstPage"));` But how to make the text field available on the second page to show the same.

Comment: You have some extra method that you write on FirstPage that you can call in the setVisible method of second page.

Comment: I see I am able to. When user inputs something on first page and clicks next, i want to fetch some data from external system.Which methods is the correct place to place such a logic?

Comment: I would use the getContainer().run(...) in getNextPage.

Comment: `IWizardPage getNextPage(final IWizardPage page)` of the Wizard or `IWizardPage getNextPage()` of the WizardPage. Please suggest.

Comment: The WizardPage getNextPage just defaults to calling the Wizard getNextPage so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Suppose there are 3 rows created each containing 2 widgets on Page 2(when moved from Page1) inside the isVisible method. When I move back to Page 2 from Page 3, I notice that everything displayed gets doubled. the 3 rows becomes 6. How can I prevent that?

Comment: @ShirgillFarhan There is something wrong with your code if that happens. Ask a new question

Comment: I have raised this separately- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60478239/how-to-avoid-widgets-being-added-while-moving-back-and-on-then-clicking-next